# date in javascript failed to chain methods?

Tags: javascript

Found this code in a legacy project

```
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(currentYear);
d.setMonth(currentMonth);
d.setDate(currentDay);
```

Trying to chain it by doing `d.setFullYear(currentYear).setMonth(currentMonth).setDate(currentDay)` but I got error. Any better way to refactor above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chaining is not a self-purpose, there's no need to refactor this code.

However, if you want to shorten it you can use [all three parameters of `setFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot chain because those functions return timestamps, not the root object.

```js
var currentYear = '2011',
  currentMonth = '04',
  currentDay = '20';

/*********************************
 * Supply All Values             *
 * Notice the "-1" on the month  *
 *********************************/
 var d = new Date();
 d.setFullYear(currentYear,currentMonth-1,currentDay);

 console.log('Milliseconds since 1970:', d.setFullYear(currentYear,currentMonth-1,currentDay));
 console.log('Locale:',''+d);


/*********************
 * Default Day/Month *
 *********************/
 var d = new Date();
 d.setFullYear(currentYear);

 console.log( 'Default Month/Day:', ''+d );
```

Of course, if you're going to set them all in the same function, you might as well set them in the [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```js
var currentYear = '2011',
  currentMonth = '04',
  currentDay = '20';

/*********************************
 * Supply All Values             *
 * Notice the "-1" on the month  *
 *********************************/
 var d = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth - 1, currentDay);

 console.log('Milliseconds since 1970:', new Date(currentYear, currentMonth - 1, currentDay));
 console.log('Locale:', '' + d);
```

The important thing to note is the months start at `0`, so you must subtract one from whatever you expect the month to be.